# Django request.user is still authenticated after logging out

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication

I have a reactjs app with Django as backend. There's a page that has a toggle which makes an API call to the backend

```
    updateIsPaid: id =>
    instance({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': BACKEND_RECEIPTS_LIST_URL + id + '/',
        'data': id
    }),
```

and in the backend

```
class ReceiptDetailView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.,)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        receipt_id = kwargs['id']
        receipt = Receipt.objects.get(id=receipt_id)
        receipt.is_paid = not receipt.is_paid
        receipt.save()
        return Response(receipt_id, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

What I've noticed is that when I log out the user in frontend, which destroys the auth token and username stored in localstorage as well as calling django logout in the backend, when i hit the back button and jump back to the page with the toggle, I can still make the POST call and the result is still 200. What I was expecting is the POST call would return a 401.

Further investigation shows that the user, while being logged out, the user still passes the `IsAuthenticated` perm check. This really confuses me and I don't know how to block the accessibility of such user upon logout. Any idea?

EDIT:

my method to check timeout is

```
export const checkAuthTimeout = expirationTime => {
    return dispatch => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(logout())
        }, expirationTime)
    }
}
```

where `logout` is

```
export const logout = () => {
    axios.post(BACKEND_LOGOUT)
    .then(res => {
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        localStorage.removeItem('expirationDate');
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
    })
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT
    }
}
```

I am unsure of how to to `history.replace` in this case

Comment: What is the [*`authentication_classes`*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#authentication) value?

Comment: Did you try using `history.replace()` to go to the next `route` after logging out the user? Like let's suppose you want the user to go to the home page after logging out, you can do `history.replace('/home')`.

Comment: @JPG I have `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in settings.py using `TokenAuthentication`. I did not set authentication_classes in the view

Comment: @HirwaBlessing I have `history.push('/')` where `/` goes to my homepage. My issue is that when i press the back arrow to go to last page, my user is still authenticated even after logging out

Comment: @JChao `history.replace()` removes all the data stored by the browser, so when the user goes back his/her login info will not be available again.

Comment: @HirwaBlessing ah yes, this works for clicking the logout button. Is there a way to use this for a Timeout? I have a function that logs out a user once the token is not refreshed for an hour. I'm not sure how to push history into a `const`

Comment: `TokenAuthentication` doesn't have a ***logout feature*** (does it? correct me if I am wrong by showing some doc). Also, REST is ***"stateless"***  and by principle, means, REST is not aware of your previous request (whether you logged-in or not or what you have done previously). Apart from that, you are using `token` to authenticate the request, so, log-out doesn't make any sense here

Comment: @JPG I was deleting the token from my localstorage in hope that I'll send an invalid request due to no token, but that's not the case and i'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: should I not have used `isAuthenticated` for perm class or adding specific authenticaionclass in the view itself?

Comment: @JChao What do you mean by ***`localstorage`*** here? Local storage of Chome/Browser?

Comment: @JChao you can use  `setTimeout()` that will count down the lifespan of the token and then use a  `useEffect` hook to refresh the component everytime the value of that counter changes.

Comment: @JPG yes, the one you can find in Inspect -> Application -> Local Storage. i followed this series of videos to set my auth up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyei2iDA4Hs

Comment: @HirwaBlessing can you take a look of my EDIT in post? I do't know how to fit the useEffect in and, well, how to use useEffect in general